# Copying data doesn't work unless destination row is empty

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a script that moves a row of data (well only 1 cell actually) from one sheet to another, upon a certain condition being met (in this case it's onEdit when Col17 = "Yes"). I'm selecting the data to move using:

```
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).copyTo(target);
```

Where 's' is Active Sheet and 'targetSheet' is the Destination Sheet.

This works perfectly when my destination sheet is blank.

However, I want to fill the other columns of my destination sheet with data, and have this script operate only in Column A. As soon as I add data to any other column, my script inserts the copied value below any existing data **regardless of whether or not there is data in Column A.**

E.g. I have 1,2,3 in Cells A1, A2 and A3 then A,B,C,D,E in Cells B1,B2,B3,B4 and B5. I run my script. New data is inserted into A6 (the first totally empty row). I want it to go to A4 (the first empty row in Col A).

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be because you have some data in the actual lastRow of the spreadsheet. And there is no lastRow+1 row in the spreadsheet.
When ever you insert data to lastRow of a spreadsheet its always better to insert a row after the lastRow and then add the data.

```
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow());
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).copyTo(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got fed up with the getLastRow function - whenever I provided it a range getLastRow would also just return me the number of rows in the range, rather than the number that contained data.

In the end I wrote a simple loop to count the cells containing data and used that instead. Probably not the best solution, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

Well considering your data looks like

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
   B4
   B5
```

the expected response of `.getLastRow()` will be `5`, because the last row to have data in it is row 5 in column B. Consider that you are working with a sheet. There is no way for the function to now that you want it to see where the last entry is on column A specifically. Instead you can just use `array = getRange('A:A').getValues()`, add the value to the first empty array index and use `getRange('A:A').setValues(array)` to update the column

Comment: Yes, I understood the issue with the getLastRow but all of my attempts to use getRange pointing at Col A were still returning '5'. I must've had errors in that syntax somewhere.

Thanks for the array suggestion, I think that's a cleaner solution than I managed to write with my own loop!